# Is it possible to change the temporary directory used by HUE when exporting to Excel?

Tags: linux, cloudera, hue

I´m doing some tests with HUE here (Cloudera) but sometimes I´m getting 100% in /tmp (Linux, not HDFS) when I try to export my results to a excel file. It´s a big table and I can´t just increase /tmp. Is there any parameter to change this tmpdir used by HUE from /tmp to another dir?

I´ve tried some parameter in hue.ini, but could not find anything related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [HUE-8747](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-8747), results should be processed and exported outside of the Hue server, and this should fix it. [Currently](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/data_export.py#L50), I don't think that there is a config parameter to change the tmp location.

One potential "trick" would be to export the results as CSV instead.